# Type Checking in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, into-outfile

So I'm using to run the following query to dump my table to a CSV file:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'testout.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM dbname.tblname;
```

This works fine, but all of the fields are being surrounded by double quotes. I'd like to get it so that only the varchar (i.e. string) fields are surrounded by quotes in the output. Is there any easy way to do this? It would probably involve type-checking fields in the query somehow, but I don't have the slightest clue for how to approach this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY it should already do as you want:

> If you specify OPTIONALLY, the ENCLOSED BY character is used only to enclose values from columns that have a string data type (such as CHAR, BINARY, TEXT, or ENUM):
>
> ```
> 1,"a string",100.20
> 2,"a string containing a , comma",102.20
> 3,"a string containing a \" quote",102.20
> 4,"a string containing a \", quote and comma",102.20
> ```

Are you sure that you don't have varchar columns for every column?

Comment: You're right, thank you! I was unioning the results with a list of the column names, which must have messed up the quotes for basic types. Is there an easy way to add the column names as the first row of the output that won't break the double quotes?

Comment: I tried that, still created the problem described in original post. It makes sense, since the cols must be the same type I guess. There's probably no easy way around this.